# Rails Nested Model Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

At the moment I have three models:

```
Songs have many Setlists through Allocations
Setlists have many Songs through Allocations
Allocations belong to Setlists and belong to Songs
```

My form at the moment looks like:

```
 <%=f.label :date, "Set a date" %>
 <%=f.date_select :date%>

 <div>
  <%= render 'song' %> 
 </div>

 <%=f.submit "Create Setlist", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

the song partial given above is:

```
<div id="songSelection">
<table class= "table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Add to Set</th>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
      <% @songs.each do |song| %>
        <tr>
           <%= nested_form_for(@setlist.allocations.build(song_id: song.id)) do |builder| %>
           <td><%= song.title %></td>
           <td><%= song.artist %></td>
           <td>
              <%= builder.submit "Add Song", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary" %>
            <% end %>
           </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Basically I'm trying to assign songs to setlists through allocations. At the moment it states that the f in the songs partial isn't defined. If I get rid of it then the page renders fine but doesn't function properly (i.e. whenever I click the button to add a song it redirects it saves the changes to the setlist date but doesn't assign any new allocations). Any help would be much appreciated. I realize that I may have missed out information as I'm somewhat new to this so if any additional details are needed please ask.

I've tried using the nested form gem by Ryan Bates but I couldn't get it working. I think it's because it's not assigning a song id to the allocation when it goes to try and build it but not sure where/how I'd put that in.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Comment: I've tried using this but I'm still having issues...Here's my code:

 `<tbody>
      <% @songs.each do |song| %>
            <tr>
               <%= nested_form_for(@setlist.allocations.build(song_id: song.id)) do |builder| %>
               <td><%= song.title %></td>
               <td><%= song.artist %></td>
               <td><%= song.key %></td>
               <td>
                  <%= builder.submit "Add Song", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary" %>
                <% end %>
               </td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
     </tbody>`

Comment: Whoops that didn't format at all! Will post it in the actual question